# How To Avoid The Firewll error due to an Apostrophe (’) in a URL generated

Tags: url, url-rewriting, qlikview

I'm working on QlikView and there is requirement that a URL would be generated using the filters that I have selected in QV and then it would be parse to another application.  The url contains the values that I have selected in QV.  We are facing an issue due to the and apostrophe (') in the user name.

Below is url generated.  You could see, the generated url is not completely treated as a URL due to the apostrophe.

**http://abcworld.com/berlin/cgi-bin/berlinisapi.dll?b_action=berlinViewer&ui.action=run.prompt=false&p_Type=E&p_Tra=Paul O'Donnell&p_AdjType=O&p_UD=2014-08-11**

How to overcome this issue?  Is there any special character that I could replace it with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to encode the apostrophe as `%27`. This is called [URL Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and is useful when you need to insert characters in a URI that can't normally be represented in a URI, or otherwise have special meaning, like a question mark. Spaces are often encoded as `%20`. So your final URL might be:

> http://abcworld.com/berlin/cgi-bin/berlinisapi.dll?b_action=berlinViewer&ui.action=run.prompt=false&p_Type=E&p_Tra=Paul%20O%27Donnell&p_AdjType=O&p_UD=2014-08-11

Comment: In the url, you have %290.  It should be %29 right?

Comment: @arunpandiyarajhen It should have been `%20` for the space.

Comment: I got it.  It must be a typo.  Thanks for your help :)